# TFS 2015 online not able to see many options.

Tags: tfs

[image]

The above is the picture which has lot options to create requirement-based suites which i am not able to see on my TFS online. Do i have to change some setting to make it visible. the below is my TFS online image.
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a support related question for the tool being referred. Should contact the Support team of that tool vendor!